# MySQL How to update updated_by field only when new data is saved or inserted

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I have a frontend PHP application which will save data in a MySQL database. The **`updated_by`** value will change since it will be the user who is updating the record.
**I would like to update the `updated_by` column ONLY when we are inserting new values for any of the other columns (`sname`, `scol2`) , and the record is inserted or updated.**
Any help is welcome, thank you so much :)



**Table Info:**

- **Table**: `test`
- **Unique Index:** columns `sname` and `scol2`
- **Columns:** `sname`, `scol2`, `updated_at`, `updated_by`
- **Values:** *name1, col2, 03-02-2013, phpuser1*

**MySQL 5.6 Info:** 
[INSERT INTO.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):  
"..returns 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated..."



**Example: users will Update or Insert records:** 


`INSERT INTO test(sname) VALUES("name1") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sname="name1", scol2="col2";` 
Result: The above query will not update anything. Perfect.

`INSERT INTO test(sname) VALUES("name1") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sname="name1", scol2="col22";` 
Result: The above query would update the columns: **`scol2`** and **`updated_at`** .Perfect. 


**How to automatically update the updated_by column in one query?** 


`INSERT INTO test(sname) VALUES("test1") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sname="name1", scol2="col2", updated_by="phpuser2222";` 
This wont work, it will update everytime the columns **`updated_by`** and **`updated_at`** 


**Possible solution with two queries:**

1. Insert the record with: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`
2. Get the return value in my PHP application to know if it has been [updated or inserted], and then update the field **`updated_by`** with a second query: `INSERT INTO test(updated_by) VALUES("phpuser2222");`

Comment: Have you tried to use triggers? add a field `created_by` and put it's values in `updated_by` in trigger body, whenever your condition is met.

Comment: never used them, I will check triggers ty :)